# Finding a function that satisfies this property.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $f\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb{C})$, that $0 < \alpha < 1$ and that
$$(T_{\alpha}f)(x) = \int_0^{x^{\alpha}}f(y)dy$$
is continuous (which is actually something you can prove)
I need to find an $f\not = 0$ a.e. such that
\begin{equation}(1) \mbox{     ....... } \int_0^{x^{\alpha}}f(y)dy = (1-\alpha) f(x) .\end{equation}
In tecnical terms I want to show $(1-\alpha)$ is an eigenvalue for the operator $T_{\alpha}$ by showing there is an associated eigenvector.

---

I could only observe that since the left hand side in (1) is continuous, then $f$ (on the right) is too, so that going back on the left we have $f$ is $C^1$,... and so on; so I think we can deduce that $f\in C^\infty$, but also deriving (1) I could not get anywhere.

Would you be able to give me some hints or a way to find such a function? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe one can use a fixed point theorem, but I am not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, the usual method of differentiating the integral equation does not really help here (it leads to a [functional differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation)). I am not aware of a general strategy for solving problems of this kind, but in this particular case simply guessing that the solution has the form $f(x) = x^\beta$ works out. Plug this ansatz into the integral equation and you should get

> $$  \beta = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} \, . $$

Comment: Thank you thats clever. I was trying to do the same but with less constrictions:

Comment: in particular I know that for $0<\alpha<1$ I have that the spectrum radius is $1-\alpha$: this is becouse I had shown it is $\le 1-\alpha$, and now you have found that $1-\alpha$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: But now would it be convenient to let $0<\gamma < 1-\alpha$ and solve $\int_0^{x^{\alpha}}f(y)dy = \gamma f(x)$ again?

Comment: In trying to do so I found that if $f(x)=x^\beta$, you get exactly: $\gamma = 1-\alpha$, which we dont want. I think I have also shown that for any polynomial it doesn't work either.

Comment: To make my intentions clearer: I think that $1-\alpha$ is the only eigenvalue, I was just trying to show it is (thank you) and now that it is the only one.

Comment: @Measureme Although it seems reasonable that there are no other eigenvalues (as you said, simple eigenvectors do not work for $\gamma \neq 1 - \alpha$), I really do not know how one could prove it.